# Declarative Authenication, Unable to register user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

I'm using declarative authentication but when ever I' click on the link to register a user I am told you are not allow to view that page. I even get this when giving guest omnipotence.

authorization_rules

```
authorization do

  role :guest do
    has_omnipotence
    #has_permission_on :channels, :to => :read
    #has_permission_on :user_session, :to => [:create, :read]
    #has_permission_on :users, :to => [:manage, :read, :update, :update]
  end

  role :admin do
    has_omnipotence
  end

  role :moderator do
    has_permission_on :channels, :to => :manage
    has_permission_on :users, :to => :read
    has_permission_on :messages , :to => :manage
  end
end

privileges do
  # default privilege hierarchies to facilitate RESTful Rails apps
  privilege :manage, :includes => [:create, :read, :update, :delete]
  privilege :read, :includes => [:index, :show]
  privilege :register, :includes => [:new, :create]
  privilege :update, :includes => :edit
  privilege :delete, :includes => :destroy
end
```

users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

   filter_resource_access

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.xml
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.xml
  def show
    #@user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.xml
  def new
    #@user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    #@user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    #@user = User.new(params[:user])
    #@user.roles << 'subscriber'
    @user.channels << Channel.find(1)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to(:channels, :notice => 'Registration successfully.') }
        format.xml { render :xml => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def profile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end



  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.xml
  def update
  #@user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.xml
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(users_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end

  def delete
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to :users
  end

  def subs
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

layout view

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= h(yield(:title) || "Untitled") %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
    <%= yield(:head) %>
  </head>
  <body>

  <ul id="nav">

    <li>
      <% if current_user %>
          <%= link_to "Logout: " + current_user.login, :logout %>
      <%else %>
              <%= link_to "Login", :login %>
          <% end %>
    </li>
    <li><%= link_to "Users", :users %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Channels", :channels %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "My Profile", :profile %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "My Channels", '#'%></li>
    <% if current_user %>
    <li></li>
        <% else %>
    <li> <%= link_to "Register", new_user_path %></li>
        <% end %>
</ul>

    <div id="container">
      <%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
        <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
      <%- end -%>

      <%- if show_title? -%>
        <h1><%=h yield(:title) %></h1>
      <%- end -%>

      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try giving explicit authorization for guests to create user?

```
  role :guest do
    has_permission_on :users, :to => [:register] 
  end
```